# How to change eve's IP address?

Tags: python, mongodb, ip, eve

When I run the `api.py` the default IP address is `127.0.0.1:5000` which is the local host. I am running the eve scripts on the server side. Am I able to change that IP address to server's address? or Am I just access it using server's address.

For example,
if the server's address is `11.5.254.12`, then I run the `api.py`. 
Am I able to access it outside of the server using `11.5.254.12:5000` or is there any way to change it from `127.0.0.1` to `11.5.254.12`?

Comment: Yes, you can change the IP address in the code. The best way would be to pass it as a parameter to the script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a parameter to your `app.run()`. By default it runs on localhost, change it to `app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')` to run on your machine IP address.