# Python eve api access in client machine

Tags: python, api, eve

I want to access the rest api of the python eve in client machine.
Here is my code,

```
MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGO_PORT = 27017
MONGO_USERNAME = ''
MONGO_PASSWORD = ''
MONGO_DBNAME = 'test'
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']
cust = {
          'item_title': 'Custmer Detail',
          'cache_control': 'max-age=10,must-revalidate',
          'cache_expires': 10,
          'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
          'schema': {
                        "CUSTOMERID" : {    'type': 'string' },
                        "COMPANYNAME": {    'type': 'string' }
          }
       }
DOMAIN = {'Customers': cust}
```

I get the output in my local machine but I want to know how to configure the Host and Port to access this table in client or another machine.

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681689/how-to-change-eves-ip-address/40690062#40690062). Quoting from that one answer:

> Add a parameter to your `app.run()`. By default it runs on localhost, change it to `app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')` to run on your machine IP address.